# How to check whether a row contains certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check whether Row 1 of my active sheet named "Exceptions" contains the text "Control  Date" (two spaces) or "Control Date".

My code finds the condition false.

```vb
Dim a As Range
Dim exceptions As Worksheet
Set exceptions = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exceptions")
For Each c In Exceptions.Range("A1:Z1")
    If c = "Control  Date" Then
        Cells.Find(What:="control  date", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    
    Else
        Cells.Find(What:="Control Date", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    End If
Next c
```

Example of a worksheet with two spaces in "Control  Date"
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify, you have "Control Date" twice in your question? `contains the text "Control Date" or "Control Date"`

Comment: When c = "Control  Date", why search again for nearly the same text?  Please share with us the text of the column headings that are being searched, so that we can also see the data.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the post for clarity.

Comment: @donPablo The search is so that my macro selects the column with the control date, makes a new column, then fills that new column with the control date & control number. Currently, I must remove the extra space between control date before running the macro on these types of worksheets, but I'd like to not have to deal with that anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to write the condition

As far as checking if the cell value is "Control Date" with a single space or one  with two spaces, there are two ways of going about it:

#### Use the `like` operator

The [like operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) makes it easy to compare a string to a basic pattern. In this example, using the wildcard character `*` *(Zero or more characters)* will return true regardless of how many spaces are between `Control` and `Date`.

```vb
If cell.Value2 Like "Control*Date" Then
    ' Do something with that cell
End If
```

#### Use the `or` operator

Using the [or operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/or-operator) ok to use as well, although not a flexible and perhaps a bit more difficult to see what's going on for your specific example.

```vb
If cell.Value2 = "Control Date" Or cell.Value2 = "Control  Date" Then
    ' Do something with that cell
End If
```

---

## Worksheet Codename

Each worksheet has whats called a [codename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename). This is a reference that can be called directly in the code to that specific worksheet by it's name.

To set this name, in the properties window update the `name` property

[image: IDE Properites window]

So instead of

```vb
Dim Exceptions As Worksheet
Set Exceptions = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exceptions")
For Each cell In Exceptions.Range("A1:Z1")
    ' Do something...
Next cell
```

you can call the worksheet reference directly

```vb
For Each cell In Exceptions.Range("A1:Z1")
    ' Do something...
Next cell
```

---

## Putting it together

- Instead of using `c` for your variable, I like to make my variables easier to read and follow so I used `cell`.
- Also, instead of hard coding your header columns in range, you could loop the cells of the entire first row. This is option suggestion though.
- Lastly, be more explicit in what property you are looking for in your `Cell`. In my example I use [`.value2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2) to show I am looking for the value of that cell.

```vb
Public Sub Demo()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Exceptions.Rows(1).Cells
        If cell.Value2 Like "Control*Date" Then
            ' Do something with that cell
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Please note that column 16 and 17 have other text in the header cells.

Comment: Adding a `*` character to the start `If cell.Value2 Like "*Control*Date" Then` would be adequate for ignoring text before as well

Answer (score 0):

Why duplicate the data into a third column?  Whenever you need the "combined" date, just go get it, but do not store it twice.

```
Option Explicit    '<<-- always have this


Sub doFindControl()

    Dim a As Range
    Dim c As Range  '<<-- add this
    Dim colDate As Long, colNumber As Long, colBlank As Long  '<<--add this
    Dim exceptions As Worksheet
    Set exceptions = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exceptions")
    For Each c In exceptions.Range("A1:Z1")
    
        ' first find the 2 key columns
        If InStr(c, "Control") > 0 Then
        
            If InStr(c, "Date") > 0 Then
                colDate = c.Column
            
            ElseIf InStr(c, "Number") > 0 Then
                colNumber = c.Column
            End If
        ' second look for the first blank column for you to put results in
        ElseIf c.Text = "" Then
                colBlank = c.Column
                Exit For    ' stop looking after its found
        End If
        
    Next c

    ' now you have the 2 FROM columns, and the TO column
    MsgBox (colDate & " " & colNumber & " " & colBlank)
    ' and you can loop thru all the rest of the rows doing combine

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers! Robert Todar's answer led me to my lightbulb moment, and I can't believe at how simple the answer was. All I had to do was change this code:

```
Cells.Find(What:="Control Date", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

to:

```
Cells.Find(What:="Control*Date", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```